# Interval Halving Method Root Interval

Tags: real-analysis

I want to use the interval halving method on 5 iterations for $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$ in the interval $\left[\frac{\pi}{3},\pi\right]$.

$1$st iteration: $\left[\frac{2\pi}{3},\pi\right]$

$2$nd iteration: $\left[\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right]$

$3$rd iteration: Midpoint $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ $=0$. This is my confusion. I am supposed to find the interval returned by the interval halving method after $5$ iterations. So what shall I do?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Analysis: “The number n of iterations needed to achieve a required tolerance ε (that is, an error guaranteed to be at most ε), is **bounded by** ...” Of course that number can be less.

Comment: @SeanRoberson so I have done it correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you have found the optimal solution. The unique solution in the interval is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Bisection method as shown in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Analysis) does return a value rather than an interval if the solution is found.

If you insist to write it in the interval form, we can write it in the form of $[\frac{3\pi}4, \frac{3\pi}4]$.